# Posting data from request object, and manually assigned values in the same create method?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to post all validated data taken from users input, along with data that isn't input, it's retrieved automatically. Such as the ip.

Instead of having multiple instances of 
`name = $request->name`, I want to DRY my code.

Can something like this be done

```
$user = User::create([
        $request->all(),
        'status'  => 1,
        'term_condition_submitted_on' => Carbon::now(),
        'user_ip' => request()->ip(),
        'confirmation_code' => md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)),
        'confirmed' => 1,
      ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to use the `merge()` function on the request:

```
$request->merge([
    'status' => 1,
    'term_condition_submitted_on' => Carbon::now(),
    'user_ip' => request()->ip(),
    'confirmation_code' => md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)),
    'confirmed' => 1,
]);

$user = User::create($request->all());
```

This will merge the `$request` with the array you pass it, as the function name suggests, then you can simply use `->create($request->all());` to create your `User` from the modified `$request` object.

Answer (score 1):

No, you'd end up with a multi-dimensional array if you pass an array inside of another array.

You can use array_merge to merge two arrays:

```
array_merge($request->all(), [
    'status'  => 1,
    'term_condition_submitted_on' => Carbon::now(),
    'user_ip' => request()->ip(),
    'confirmation_code' => md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)),
    'confirmed' => 1,
]);
```

The difference with array_merge and append (with the + operator) is array_merge will overwrite occurrences in the first array with the second array, so your manual values will always take precedent.